# Ext-JS 4.1 - How to load static XML data into Ext.data.TreeStore

Tags: extjs

I was wondering if someone could point me in the direction of where I could find an example of a Ext.data.TreeStore being loaded from a static XML string (i.e. not from a file)?  Or provide a short example?

I have seen plenty of examples where you can load it from a AJAX call to a server, but I have not been able to locate a single example where it is loaded with static XML JavaScript string that you could have embedded in your application file.

Would really appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an XML store. Take a look at this:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.XmlStore

edit: The above might not work for trees. You can set the reader of your proxy on XML though:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {

                    model: 'my.Model',  

                    proxy: {  
                        type: 'ajax',
                        url : 'path/to.xml',
                        reader: {
                            type: 'xml',
                            root: 'data'
                        }
                    },

                    root: {
                        expanded: true
                    }

                });
```

Comment: Hi Johan, actually I was looking for an example where the XML is read through a Ext.data.proxy.Memory object.  This is what I am having trouble getting to work.  I have the XML I want to display already in the program.  Would you know of an example that could show how to do this?  I've seen plenty with JSON, but nothing with XML.  Thanks for getting back to me.